# Is there a Node js framework that allows creation of PHP like pages?

Tags: php, node.js

Is there any framework or library that allows you to make PHP like pages?

A "PHP like page" is a page that can contain code embedded in HTML - basically a spaghetti code.

So it would be something like:

```js
<?
var con = dbmanager.connect(.....);
var entries = con.execute_sql(....);
?>
<div class="entries">
    <?for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++){
        var entry = entries[i];
    ?>
    <div class="entry"> <?=entry['name']?> </div>
    <?}?>
</div>
```

Small note: All the examples about Node seems to be more or less about microservices or MVC architecture.

**I would prefer a real answer and not minuses from those that are Node purist. Minuses will not answer this question.**

Comment: you can use ejs, pug, jade, hjs

Comment: The minuses may be more about asking for recommendations, which SO isn't about. [Where can I ask about “finding a tool, library, or favorite off-site resource?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource)

Comment: I prefer express-hbs

Comment: @NigelRen I must admit the phrasing was not the most appropriate as I'm more in search of a solution than just a simple recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EJS - Embedded JavaScript](https://ejs.co/)

The syntax looks like this:

```
<div class="entries">
  <% for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++ { %>
    <div class="entry"> <%= entries[i].name %> </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```